# Yandex Директ - You need to fill out an app access request in the Direct interface and wait for confirmation

Tags: php

Ребят, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Пытаюсь реализовать подключение к Яндекс Директу через пхп nuSOAP class. Но мне каждый раз, почему-то, выдает ошибку:

> "You need to fill out an app access request in the Direct interface and wait for confirmation."

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже не понимаю в чем проблема. Процедуру получения токена повторил заново уже раз 5, наверное. Все равно не работает.

Вот мой код

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
# подключаем библиотеку NuSOAP 
require_once('nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php');

# метод API
$method = 'GetClientInfo';

# авторизационный токен
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

# локаль
$locale = 'ru';

# путь к WSDL
$wsdlurl = 'https://api.direct.yandex.ru/v4/wsdl/';

#######################################################

# создаем клиента 
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdlurl, 'wsdl');

# параметры клиента 
$client->authtype = 'basic';
$client->decode_utf8 = 0;
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

# добавляем заголовки 
$headers =
    "<token>$token</token>
     <locale>$locale</locale>";

$client->setHeaders($headers);

# отправляем запрос
$result = $client->call('GetClientInfo');

# вывод результата 
print_r($result);

?>
```

Что с этим делать?

Comment: Вот исправленный NuSOAP, который работает c Яндекс Директ API v5: https://github.com/proxy-m/nusoap

Comment: Рабочий пример исправленного NuSOAP для Яндекс Директ API v5: https://github.com/proxy-m/nusoap/blob/master/samples/client4yandex.php

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос, если кому нужно - пользуйтесь.

[Ответ на вопрос](http://direct-automate.ru/directautomate/index/board/29785873/)

> Sego, Важная информация для пользователей Директ автомат версии 1.3 или ниже.
>
> Если в логе ошибок (/files/log/error.txt) появилась ошибка "No access: Необходимо заполнить для приложения заявку на доступ в интерфейсе Директа и дождаться её подтверждения", то вы можете перейти на версию 1.4. Обновление стоит 500 рублей.
>
> Если вы не хотите обновляться, то проблема решается переполучением токена вручную по следующей схеме:
>
> 1. Залогиньтесь под логином, в котором требуется получить или обновить токен.
> 2. Пройдите по ссылке: [https://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=...](http://oauth.yandex.ru/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=f5ff8f217d0d44b59d6e6e1d335e13f5)
> 3. Нажмите кнопку "Разрешить" доступ приложению Директ автомат.
> 4. Скопируйте из адресной строки браузера токен (`#access_token=ТОКЕН&token_type=bearer&expires_in=31536000`).
> 5. Отредактируйте аккаунт в программе директ автомат и впишите полученный токен.

Comment: Не цитируйте текст картинкой, вставляйте его как текст.

Comment: Какие шаги из этого ответа помогли? Что вы до этого не делали, что не работало?

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что вы обращаетесь к корректному адресу.
Если у вас доступ открыт только в песочницу, то обращаясь к

`https://api.direct.yandex.ru/...`

вы будете получать ошибку доступа.
В этом случае стоит обращаться к

`https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.ru/...`